# meaning of abbreviations h and m in Na channels

Tags: neuroscience

In a voltage-gated sodium channel, there are two gates, one for activation and one for inactivation. They are also known as h- and m- gate. What are these letters standing for?

Comment: Are the gates referred to **h-** and **m-** in a diagram or as text. I looked up online and nothing seems to mention the gates as those two letters. A citation or picture reference would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those initials were proposed by Hodgkin and Huxley in their original paper modeling the action potential in nerve cells: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodgkin%E2%80%93Huxley_model

They are **not** names for subunits, domains or motifs in the sodium channel, as your question may imply. Instead,

> n, m, and h are dimensionless quantities between 0 and 1 that are associated with potassium channel activation, sodium channel activation, and sodium channel inactivation, respectively.

However, there is no indication of what those initials mean (if anything), apparently being just letters they chose to name the variables in their equations.

Comment: It's unusual for algebra notations to use non-consecutive numbers, such as x, y, z, or p, q, r, but you seem to be right. The H&H article indeed states "m then represents the proportion of activating molecules on the inside and 1-m the proportion on the outside; h is the proportion of inactivating molecules on the outside and 1-h the proportion on the inside." Again, very unusual.

Comment: @NickSandor If this answer [addressed your problem](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Comment: My point was that I am not sure that there is no better answer. I will accept Gerardo's answer if after a few days, nothing better comes up.

Comment: @NickSandor think m and n were chosen purposely as being in sequence and both referring to activation, while h was another variable letter distinct from m and n to separate it as an "inactivation" - I'd also note that there are a *lot* of other variable names in the Hodgkin and Huxley paper: they use alpha and beta for rate constants so it's nice to avoid a & b as variable names to avoid confusion; g and V are standard for conductance and voltage, "p" might be confused with probability; q and r are typically used with p, and xyz are typically used for coordinates or more arbitrary variables.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado While you are somewhat correct that the "h-gate" "m-gate" etc terminology doesn't refer to particular domains in the channel, they *do* refer to the motifs that Hodgkin and Huxley proposed to exist, and that terminology is still used in reference to their hypotheses, which although imperfect have largely been proven true, so OP is not incorrect to refer to the "h-gate" and "m-gate" when talking about HH equations or sodium channels, the translation would be "h-gate" = "domains of the voltage-gated Na channel that contribute to inactivation"